Some Subscribers Not Called When Firing Event
I'm trying to replicate a famous card game in unity using C#, just as a challenge to myself. Today I was making a Sacrificeable script that is added to almost every card in the game. There is another script DetectClicks which fires events of different mouse inputs(Click, Enter, Exit, Release). Said script worked perfectly until today. When I was making the Sacrificeable script which subscribes a function Opposer to Click, the function just wasn't called. And testing a bit, realized that the only function called was a print used to check if the event was raised in the first place.
My question is: why does this happen? and why it didn't break before? is there a way to solve this and call all the functions?
Here is the Sacrificeable code:
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[RequireComponent(typeof(DetectClicks))]
public class Sacrificeable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CardPlay reference;
    [SerializeField] bool sacrifice;
    private bool _sacrifice;
    public bool Sacrifice
    {
        get => _sacrifice;
        set
        {
            sacrifice = _sacrifice;
            if (value == _sacrifice)
                return;
            sacrifice = _sacrifice = value;
            alternator?.Invoke();
        }
    }
    private DetectClicks detector;
    private void Start()
    {
        TryGetComponent(out CardPlay card);
        reference = reference ? reference : card;
        alternator = Selected_;
        detector = GetComponent<DetectClicks>();
        reference.OnPlay += Enable;
    }
    private Action alternator;
    private void Selected_() 
    { 
        Selected?.Invoke();
        alternator = Unselected_;
    }
    private void Unselected_()
    {
        Unselected?.Invoke();
        alternator = Selected_;
    }
    public event Action Selected;
    public event Action Unselected;
    public void Enable()
    {
        print("Enabled");
        detector.Click -= Opposer;
        detector.Click += Opposer;
    }
    private void Opposer()
    {
        Sacrifice = !Sacrifice;
    }
    private void OnValidate()
    {
        Sacrifice = sacrifice;
    }
}

And here DetectClicks:
using System;
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent(typeof(Collider2D))]
public class DetectClicks : MonoBehaviour
{
    public event Action Click;
    public event Action Release;
    public event Action Enter;
    public event Action Exit;

    public Collider[] Colliders => gameObject.GetComponents<Collider>();
    private void Awake()
    {
        Click += () => print("Truly invoked");
    }
    public void OnMouseDown()
    {
        Click();
        Debug.Log("Detected");
    }
    public void OnMouseUp() => Release?.Invoke();
    public void OnMouseEnter() => Enter?.Invoke();
    public void OnMouseExit() => Exit?.Invoke();
}

Any information and advice is well received!

Can you explain what you're trying to do? Because for the life of me I cannot comprehend this. Why do you need all this complexity? Couldn't this just be a detector.Click += ()=>{Sacrificeable = !Sacrificeable} with the Sacrificeable itself just raising an event like if(_sacrificeable) Selected?.Invoke() else Unselected?.Invoke() ? Also why do you need the extra serialized bool? It doesn't trigger anything and from the likes of it it's used more like storage/caching than user-input-driven.

As mentioned before: events in c# do not selectively break for one person - the issue is more likely that A) you are not subscribed in the moment you think you should be .. or B) maybe you are subscribed on a different instance (which basically pretty much relates to A) .. this is something involving more context than what you provide here (and what we would have a lot of ambition to run through in the head) but rather something to find out by Debugging your code with breakpoints and inspect the subscriptions etc in the moment

Does your "Click()" method call in DetectClicks need to be "Click?.Invoke()", possibly?

@NPatch it can't be detector.Click += ()=>{Sacrificeable = !Sacrificeable} because i need to unsubscribe the method from Click. Meanwhile Selected and Unselected are invoked using that alternator because i always try to avoid branches. Probably you're right and i should just use an if statement.

@derHugo actually this question is already solved and you were pretty close. The function was subscribed to the right event but the mouse click was a triggering a different Click instance. I don't know how to indicate that the question is already solved

Fine about the Opposer, but you're micro-optimizing without reason. Be aware of performance implications of what you do, but know when to try to optimize. Branches aren't always bad. There's things like branch prediction which improve performance greatly. Instead you've bloated your class with no reason. Write simple code, profile, optimize on profile data.

@NPatch there is actually nothing wrong about named methods especially when you need to unsubscribe. Performance wise I'm pretty sure the compiled code will look and perform the same. And readability seems not really affected .. personally I would go with R3 and implement this reactive but that's basically just tastes

@derHugo I'm not saying there's sth wrong with named methods. I'm saying he's added so many Actions and complexity to avoid an if statement or two which is just a waste of time for no real benefit, as you yourself said.

@derHugo What I said before about the lambda, was because there's only one unsubscribe in the given code and it's right before he resubscribes. So I said it offhand just to ask for an explanation, not because I have sth against named functions.
